# How to generate texts as image in PDF

Tags: php, html, pdf, dompdf

I am using `dompdf` to generate a PDF file. The PDF simply contains texts. I need the content of the PDF to show as an image instead of texts. I do not know where to start. Cannot find anything using Google. Any suggestions?

More info:

In the PDF I currently generated, I can select specific portion of texts by highlighting it using the mouse. In the PDF I should generate, I should not be able to select portion of texts because the texts is already an image. So the PDF I should generate contains an image, and the image contains the texts.

Comment: Mind the gap with [XY problems](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), it can lead to bad asking. - If you're looking how to create a bitmap image containing text, we have this answered on site already multiple times, just do a search.

Comment: Also see here: https://code.google.com/p/dompdf/issues/detail?id=201

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could generate a png first using phpgd / ImageMagick then shove it through dompdf